# /home: Where is it?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

Even using Ubuntu/Linux for some time, I am still a new one. I am having doubts where is the problem. Today my PC shows that the /home folder is almost full, with just 100MB free.

My four HDDs are setup as:

- sda=240GB (sda1=84GB, NTFS, Win, 32GB free; sda2=152GB, Ext4, Linux, 114GB free, as Filesytem Root; and sda3=4GB, swap);
- sdb=3TB (sdb=3TB, NTFS, 2.8TB free, as /media/WD-Blue);
- sdc=500GB (sdc1=400GB, NTFS, 43GB free, as /media/Data; sdc2=sdc5=100GB, Ext4, 4.5GB free, as /home);
- sdd=1TB (sdd1=1TB, 67GB free, as /media/WD-MyBook).

The properties for the  folder shows:

- folder (inode/directory)
- 184.864 items 42.6GB
- parent folder: /home
- free 100MB

So, where is this almost full folder located?

```
╰─$ df -h -x squashfs -x tmpfs  
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
udev            945M     0  945M   0% /dev  
/dev/sda2       139G   33G   99G  25% /  
/dev/sdc1       373G  333G   41G  90% /media/Data  
/dev/sdc5        92G   81G  6,3G  93% /home  
/dev/sdb        2,8T  175G  2,6T   7% /media/WD-Blue  
/dev/sdd1       932G  869G   63G  94% /media/WD-MyBook    

╰─$ lsblk                                                                   
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT  
fd0      2:0    1     4K  0 disk   
loop0    7:0    0     9M  1 loop /snap/canonical-livepatch/146  
loop1    7:1    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5  
loop2    7:2    0     9M  1 loop /snap/canonical-livepatch/138  
loop3    7:3    0   115M  1 loop /snap/core/13886  
loop4    7:4    0 114,9M  1 loop /snap/core/13741  
loop5    7:5    0  55,6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2560  
loop6    7:6    0  55,6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2566  
loop7    7:7    0    62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1611  
loop8    7:8    0  63,2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1623  
loop9    7:9    0   5,6M  1 loop /snap/czkawka/889  
loop10   7:10   0   1,9M  1 loop /snap/fclones/22  
loop11   7:11   0   2,3M  1 loop /snap/fclones/21  
loop12   7:12   0   103M  1 loop /snap/flacon-tabetai/60  
loop13   7:13   0  21,4M  1 loop /snap/freac/2263  
loop14   7:14   0 162,9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145  
loop15   7:15   0 164,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161  
loop16   7:16   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72  
loop17   7:17   0  22,3M  1 loop /snap/freac/2498  
loop18   7:18   0 346,3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119  
loop19   7:19   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77  
loop20   7:20   0 346,3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115  
loop21   7:21   0   140K  1 loop /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13  
loop22   7:22   0  81,3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534  
loop23   7:23   0  91,7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535  
loop24   7:24   0 110,7M  1 loop /snap/namebench-snap/4  
loop25   7:25   0 301,4M  1 loop /snap/qt5-core20/11  
loop26   7:26   0 301,3M  1 loop /snap/qt5-core20/12  
loop27   7:27   0  86,7M  1 loop /snap/simplescreenrecorder/1  
loop28   7:28   0  45,9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/599  
loop29   7:29   0  54,2M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/558  
loop30   7:30   0    48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16778  
loop31   7:31   0    48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17029  
loop32   7:32   0   4,6M  1 loop /snap/untrunc-anthwlock/163  
sda      8:0    0 223,6G  0 disk   
├─sda1   8:1    0  78,1G  0 part   
├─sda2   8:2    0 141,8G  0 part /  
└─sda3   8:3    0   3,7G  0 part [SWAP]  
sdb      8:16   0   2,7T  0 disk /media/WD-Blue  
sdc      8:32   0 465,8G  0 disk   
├─sdc1   8:33   0 372,5G  0 part /media/Data  
├─sdc2   8:34   0     1K  0 part   
└─sdc5   8:37   0  93,2G  0 part /run/timeshift/backup  
sdd      8:48   0 931,5G  0 disk   
└─sdd1   8:49   0 931,5G  0 part /media/WD-MyBook  
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: That is not a folder it is a partition.

Comment: Add the output of `df -h -x squashfs -x tmpfs` and `lsblk`, please. Use code formatting for the command output: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @David, yeah, and the /home partition (sdc5) shows 4.5GB as free. That is why I am asking.

Comment: @muru, I added the outputs in the question. I did not find any other place to it. And, certainly it is not as you request, but I hope you can understand, and give me a light.

Comment: It looks like you have both `/home` and `/run/timeshift/backup` mounted to the same partition.  Also because you have decided to put home on its own partition, it doesn't matter how much space you have anywhere else. The partition size will be a hard limit for your home folder.  Any free space on home also won't be accessible for use by directories on your system partition.

Comment: Also include the output of `mount` and eventually `cat /etc/fstab` in your question.

Comment: @Nmath the other way around: the partition `/dev/sdc5` is mounted to both `/home` and `/run/timeshift/backup`, but that isn't a problem, you can mount the same partition to multiple locations.

Comment: "Today my PC shows that the /home folder is almost full": how was this message shown? Where? What tool? Was it a notification that appeared on your desktop? Is it still happening after a reboot? I suspect you just had some files that were deleted but still open by a program so they were taking up space that is now free.

Comment: Thank you all for your attention. I really forgot to come back and enjoy all your knowledge. I believe it adjusted itself. The message asking for more space disappeared. Thanks again for your time. Yours sincerely.